# Convert a row with two columns into two rows of one column

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, union

I have two columns, `confid1` and `confid2`. They both have the same data type.

I somehow need to bring `confid2` into `confid1`, but not concatenate them. Instead, insert it into a new line under `confid1`.

Original:

```
confid1     confid2
AACII1C1    AACII1C2
```

I have tried using UNION such as below:

```
(SELECT confid1 as ID1 FROM dyndomrun)
UNION
(SELECT confid2 as ID2 FROM dyndomrun)
```

It then returns the combination of `confid1` and `confid2` inside `confid1`, which is what I was looking for, as below:

```
confid1
AACII1C1
AACII1C2
```

Now, the problem is that one of the columns in another table links up with `confid1` and `confid2`, but it is all in a single column but multiple rows.

Right now, I have tried using the same `UNION` method, just adding the `pdbcode` into the code, such as below:

```
(SELECT confid1 as id1, conformer.pdbcode from dyndomrun, conformer where dyndomrun.confid1 = conformer.id)
UNION
(SELECT confid2 as id2, conformer.pdbcode from dyndomrun, conformer where dyndomrun.confid1 = conformer.id)
```

And it returns duplicate "pdbcode" values when it's not suppose to, as below:

```
confid1,    pdbcode
AACII1C1    2a4n
AACII1C2    2a4n
```

I want it to select and return a `pdbcode` column related to `confid1` and `confid2` such as below:

```
confid1,    pdbcode
AACII1C1    2a4n
AACII1C2    1b87
```

Comment: Please don't use double quotes for values. Values are typically enclosed in single quotes. Double quotes are for identifiers and only necessary in special cases. As I advised earlier today, start by reading the [very important chapter on identifiers in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS).

Comment: Why would the column in "another table" link up with link up with `AACII1C1` and `AACII1C2` at the same time? This does not make sense without further explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your 2nd JOIN to match using confid2?

```
(SELECT confid1 as id1, conformer.pdbcode 
from dyndomrun JOIN conformer 
           ON dyndomrun.confid1 = conformer.id)
UNION
(SELECT confid2 as id2, conformer.pdbcode 
 from dyndomrun JOIN conformer 
           ON dyndomrun.confid2 = conformer.id)
```

Note: updated to use explicit JOIN syntax

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. This works as it returns the necessary pdbcode to its specific confid :)

Comment: @jeiman90: if this answer is what you like, please "accept" this with the big tick on the left

Answer (score 1):

```
(SELECT confid1 as id1, conformer.pdbcode from dyndomrun, conformer where dyndomrun.confid1 = conformer.id)
UNION
(SELECT confid2 as id2, conformer.pdbcode from dyndomrun, conformer where dyndomrun.confid2 = conformer.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make the join condition span both:

```
select  *
from    dyndomrun ddr
join    conformer as c
on      c.id in (ddr.confid1, ddr.confid2)
```

Alternatively, you can move the union to a subquery, and join that to the second table:

```
select  *
from    (
        select  confid1 as confid
        from    dyndomrun
        union all
        select  confid2 
        from    dyndomrun
        ) as ddr
join    conformer as c
on      c.id = ddr.confid
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT A.confid1, B.pdbcode
FROM (  SELECT confid1 FROM dyndomrun
        UNION
        SELECT confid2 FROM dyndomrun) A
LEFT JOIN conformer B
ON A.confid1 = B.id
```